# Does macOS's Mail app support two-factor authentication for Outlook/Hotmail email accounts?

Tags: mail.app, system-settings, hotmail

I have a MacBook Air (11-inch, mid 2012, Catalina 10.15.7) I use for travel. Since the last time I used it, I have enabled two-factor authentication (2FA) for my Microsoft Outlook (Hotmail) email address.

Mail is asking me to update my email settings/password. I enter the correct password, but macOS (`System Preferences > Internet Accounts`) fails my authentication, and never asks for the 2FA code.

Is 2FA supported in macOS's Mail app?

Comment: having the same problem with a gmx account